# Let $a,b \in \Re$. If 0 < $\epsilon$ < min{|a|, |b|}. Show this inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $a,b \in \Re$. If 0 < $\epsilon$ < min{|a|, |b|}.
$ {\frac{|a+\epsilon|}{|b+\epsilon|}} \leq {\frac{|a|+\epsilon}{|b|-\epsilon}}$

I tried to use triangular inequality.

But have no idea of changing the base from $|b|+\epsilon $ to $|b|-\epsilon$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the reverse triangle inequality:
$|b+\epsilon| \geq \big||b|-|-\epsilon|\big| = |b|-\epsilon$.

Comment: This make things clear $|b-(-\epsilon)| \geq ||b|-|-\epsilon||$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** for any $x,y$, we have $|x|-|y|\leq|x+y|$, since $$|x|=|(x-y)+y|\leq|x-y|+|y|$$
And use that $|y|=|-y|$.

Comment: why is this true? I know $|x+y| \leq |x|+|y| $

Comment: and $|x-y|\leq |x|+|y|$

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: ohhh yaa  Useful technique

Answer (score 0):

$0<|a+\epsilon|\le |a|+ \epsilon$ and $|b+\epsilon|>b-\epsilon >0$.

Comment: Ya.. This make me confuse cause ${\frac{|a+\epsilon|}{|b+\epsilon|}} \leq {\frac{|a|+\epsilon}{|b+\epsilon|}}$

Comment: and I can change the base to b-$\epsilon$ because smaller base have greater value